# I have problems using pine script v3 in version 4 (Koncorde indicator)

Tags: pine-script

I managed to convert the Koncorde indicator from version 2 to version 3 and then to 4, but I cannot see the graph of 2 variables ("azul" and "verde")

I have spent several hours and I decided to ask you because maybe for you this is easy to solve

This is the error I get:
line 14: Shadowing built-in variable 'nvi'
line 30: Shadowing built-in variable 'pvi'
line 35: Shadowing built-in variable 'nvi'
line 6: Shadowing built-in variable 'pvi'

This is the code:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Koncorde V4")

calc_pvi() =>
sval = volume
pvi = 0.0
pvi := 1.1 ? 1.1 : volume > volume[1] ? 
   nz(pvi[1]) + (close - close[1]) / close[1] * (na(pvi[1]) ? pvi[1] : sval) : 
   nz(pvi[1])
pvi

calc_nvi() =>
sval = volume
nvi = 0.01
nvi := 1 ? 1 : volume < volume[1] ? 

   nz(nvi[1]) + (close - close[1]) / close[1] * (na(nvi[1]) ? nvi[1] : sval) : 
   nz(nvi[1])
nvi

calc_mfi(length) =>
src = hlc3
upper = sum(volume * (change(src) <= 0 ? 0 : src), length)
lower = sum(volume * (change(src) >= 0 ? 0 : src), length)
rsi(upper, lower)

tprice = ohlc4
lengthEMA = input(255, minval=1)
m = input(15)
pvi = calc_pvi()
pvim = ema(pvi, m)

pvimax = highest(pvim, 90)
pvimin = lowest(pvim, 90)
oscp = (pvi - pvim) * 100 / (pvimax - pvimin)
nvi = calc_nvi()
nvim = ema(nvi, m)
nvimax = highest(nvim, 90)
nvimin = lowest(nvim, 90)
azul = (nvi - nvim) * 100 / (nvimax - nvimin)
xmf = calc_mfi(14)
mult = input(2.0)
basis = sma(tprice, 25)
dev = mult * stdev(tprice, 25)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
OB1 = (upper + lower) / 2.0
OB2 = upper - lower
BollOsc = (tprice - OB1) / OB2 * 100
xrsi = rsi(tprice, 14)
calc_stoch(src, length, smoothFastD) =>
ll = lowest(low, length)
hh = highest(high, length)
k = 100 * (src - ll) / (hh - ll)
sma(k, smoothFastD)

stoc = calc_stoch(tprice, 21, 3)
marron = (xrsi + xmf + BollOsc + stoc / 3) / 2
verde = marron + oscp
media = ema(marron, m)
bandacero = 0

vl = plot(verde, color=#66FF66, style=plot.style_area, title="verde")  // COLOURED(102,255,102) as “verde” , GREEN
ml = plot(marron, color=#FFCC99, style=plot.style_area, title="marron", transp=0)  // COLOURED(255,204,153) as"marron" , BEIGE
al = plot(azul, color=#00FFFF, style=plot.style_area, title="azul")  // COLOURED(0,255,255) as “azul” ,
plot(marron, color=#330000, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2, title="lmarron")  // COLOURED(51,0,0) as “lmarron” ,
plot(verde, color=#006600, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2, title="lineav")  // COLOURED(0,102,0) as “lineav” ,
plot(azul, color=#000066, style=plot.style_line, title="lazul")  // COLOURED(0,0,102) as “lazul” ,
plot(media, color=color.red, title="media", style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2)  // COLOURED(255,0,0) as “media” ,
plot(bandacero, color=color.black, title="cero")  // COLOURED(0,0,0) as "cero"
```

I would appreciate for any help.

Regards,
Luciano

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that [nvi](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#var_nvi) and [pvi](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/#var_pvi) are built-in variables, and you used those as your own variables to which you assigned values. You can't assign your own values to built-in variables.
I've changed the names in your code to `my_pvi`, `my_nvi`, `mypvi` and `mynvi`.
This will work:

```
//@version=4
study(title="Koncorde V4")

calc_pvi() =>
    sval = volume
    my_pvi = 0.0
    my_pvi := 1.1 ? 1.1 : volume > volume[1] ? 
       nz(my_pvi[1]) + (close - close[1]) / close[1] * (na(my_pvi[1]) ? my_pvi[1] : sval) : 
       nz(my_pvi[1])
    my_pvi

calc_nvi() =>
    sval = volume
    my_nvi = 0.01
    my_nvi := 1 ? 1 : volume < volume[1] ? 
    
       nz(my_nvi[1]) + (close - close[1]) / close[1] * (na(my_nvi[1]) ? my_nvi[1] : sval) : 
       nz(my_nvi[1])
    my_nvi

calc_mfi(length) =>
    src = hlc3
    upper = sum(volume * (change(src) <= 0 ? 0 : src), length)
    lower = sum(volume * (change(src) >= 0 ? 0 : src), length)
    rsi(upper, lower)

tprice = ohlc4
lengthEMA = input(255, minval=1)
m = input(15)
mypvi = calc_pvi()
pvim = ema(mypvi, m)

pvimax = highest(pvim, 90)
pvimin = lowest(pvim, 90)
oscp = (mypvi - pvim) * 100 / (pvimax - pvimin)
mynvi = calc_nvi()
nvim = ema(mynvi, m)
nvimax = highest(nvim, 90)
nvimin = lowest(nvim, 90)
azul = (mynvi - nvim) * 100 / (nvimax - nvimin)
xmf = calc_mfi(14)
mult = input(2.0)
basis = sma(tprice, 25)
dev = mult * stdev(tprice, 25)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
OB1 = (upper + lower) / 2.0
OB2 = upper - lower
BollOsc = (tprice - OB1) / OB2 * 100
xrsi = rsi(tprice, 14)
calc_stoch(src, length, smoothFastD) =>
    ll = lowest(low, length)
    hh = highest(high, length)
    k = 100 * (src - ll) / (hh - ll)
    sma(k, smoothFastD)

stoc = calc_stoch(tprice, 21, 3)
marron = (xrsi + xmf + BollOsc + stoc / 3) / 2
verde = marron + oscp
media = ema(marron, m)
bandacero = 0

vl = plot(verde, color=#66FF66, style=plot.style_area, title="verde")  // COLOURED(102,255,102) as “verde” , GREEN
ml = plot(marron, color=#FFCC99, style=plot.style_area, title="marron", transp=0)  // COLOURED(255,204,153) as"marron" , BEIGE
al = plot(azul, color=#00FFFF, style=plot.style_area, title="azul")  // COLOURED(0,255,255) as “azul” ,
plot(marron, color=#330000, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2, title="lmarron")  // COLOURED(51,0,0) as “lmarron” ,
plot(verde, color=#006600, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2, title="lineav")  // COLOURED(0,102,0) as “lineav” ,
plot(azul, color=#000066, style=plot.style_line, title="lazul")  // COLOURED(0,0,102) as “lazul” ,
plot(media, color=color.red, title="media", style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2)  // COLOURED(255,0,0) as “media” ,
plot(bandacero, color=color.black, title="cero")  // COLOURED(0,0,0) as "cero"
```

New code 08 dec 2020

```
//@version=4
study(title="Koncorde Inversiones en el Mundo")
calc_pvi() =>
    sval=volume
    // mypvi=(volume > volume[1]) ? nz(pvi[1]) + ((close - close[1])/close[1]) * (na(pvi[1]) ? pvi[1] : sval) : nz(pvi[1])
    // mypvi
    (volume > volume[1]) ? nz(pvi[1]) + ((close - close[1])/close[1]) * (na(pvi[1]) ? pvi[1] : sval) : nz(pvi[1])
    
calc_nvi() =>
    sval=volume
    // mynvi=(volume < volume[1]) ? nz(nvi[1]) + ((close - close[1])/close[1]) * (na(nvi[1]) ? nvi[1] : sval) : nz(nvi[1])
    // mynvi
    (volume < volume[1]) ? nz(nvi[1]) + ((close - close[1])/close[1]) * (na(nvi[1]) ? nvi[1] : sval) : nz(nvi[1])
    
calc_mfi(length) =>
    src=hlc3
    upper = sum(volume * (change(src) <= 0 ? 0 : src), length)
    lower = sum(volume * (change(src) >= 0 ? 0 : src), length)
    rsi(upper, lower)

var float mypvi = na
var float pvim = na
var float pvimax = na
var float pvimin = na
var float oscp = na

var float mynvi = na
var float nvim = na
var float nvimax = na
var float nvimin = na

var float xmf = na
var float basis = na
var float dev = na
var float upper = na
var float lower = na
var float OB1 = na
var float OB2 = na
var float BollOsc = na
var float xrsi = na
var float stoc = na
var float azul = na
var float marron = na
var float verde = na
var float media = na
var float bandacero = 0

tprice=ohlc4
lengthEMA = input(255, minval=1)
m=input(15)
mypvi := calc_pvi(), plotchar(mypvi, "mypvi", "")
pvim := ema(mypvi, m), plotchar(pvim, "pvim", "")
pvimax := highest(pvim, 90), plotchar(pvimax, "pvimax", "")
pvimin := lowest(pvim, 90), plotchar(pvimin, "pvimin", "")
oscp := (mypvi - pvim) * 100/ (pvimax - pvimin)
mynvi :=calc_nvi()
nvim := ema(mynvi, m)
nvimax := highest(nvim, 90)
nvimin := lowest(nvim, 90)
azul := (mynvi - nvim) * 100/ (nvimax - nvimin)
xmf := calc_mfi(14)
mult = input(2.0)
basis := sma(tprice, 25)
dev := mult * stdev(tprice, 25)
upper := basis + dev
lower := basis - dev
OB1 := (upper + lower) / 2.0
OB2 := upper - lower
BollOsc := ((tprice - OB1) / OB2 ) * 100
xrsi := rsi(tprice, 14)
calc_stoch(src, length,smoothFastD ) =>
    ll = lowest(low, length)
    hh = highest(high, length)
    k = 100 * (src - ll) / (hh - ll)
    sma(k, smoothFastD)

stoc := calc_stoch(tprice, 21, 3)
marron := (xrsi + xmf + BollOsc + (stoc / 3))/2
verde := marron + oscp
media := ema(marron,m)
// bandacero= 0

vl=plot(verde, color=#66FF66, style=plot.style_area, title="verde")// COLOURED(102,255,102) as “verde” , GREEN
ml=plot(marron, color= #FFCC99, style=plot.style_area, title="marron", transp=0) // COLOURED(255,204,153) as"marron" , BEIGE
al=plot(azul, color=#00FFFF, style=plot.style_area, title="azul") // COLOURED(0,255,255) as “azul” ,
plot(marron, color= #330000, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2, title="lmarron") // COLOURED(51,0,0) as “lmarron” ,
plot(verde, color=#006600, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2, title="lineav") // COLOURED(0,102,0) as “lineav” ,
plot(azul, color=#000066, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2, title="lazul") // COLOURED(0,0,102) as “lazul” ,
plot(media, color=color.red, title="media", style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2) // COLOURED(255,0,0) as “media” ,
plot(bandacero, color=color.black, title="cero") // COLOURED(0,0,0) as "cero"
```

Comment: Dear @Bjorn Mistiaen,
Thanks for your help, but I still can't see below graph:

vl = plot(verde, color=#66FF66, style=plot.style_area, title="verde")
al = plot(azul, color=#00FFFF, style=plot.style_area, title="azul") 
plot(verde, color=#006600, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2, title="lineav")
plot(azul, color=#000066, style=plot.style_line, title="lazul")

I copy and paste your code, and now there is not error related to built-in variables, but I see the same as my original code.
Here you can see how It should looks:
https://es.tradingview.com/script/oln2f979/

Comment: I added the new code which shows them, but the plot doesn't look like the original indicator. Not sure what's wrong. Why don't you just use the version like it's posted by the author? That'll work.

Comment: Dear, I want to use the version 4 because I want to combine this indicator with other indicator version 4.

Answer (score 0):

This version works fine

```
//@version=4
strategy(title="Estrategia Koncorde V4 Prueba")
srcTprice = input(ohlc4, title="Fuente para Precio Total")
srcMfi = input(hlc3, title="Fuente MFI", group="Money Flow Index")
tprice=srcTprice

//lengthEMA = input(255, minval=1)
m=input(15, title="Media Exponencial")
longitudPVI=input(90, title="Longitud PVI")
longitudNVI=input(90, title="Longitud NVI")
longitudMFI=input(14, title="Longitud MFI")

pvim = ema(pvi, m)
pvimax = highest(pvim, longitudPVI)
pvimin = lowest(pvim, longitudPVI)
oscp = (pvi - pvim) * 100/ (pvimax - pvimin)

nvim = ema(nvi, m)
nvimax = highest(nvim, longitudNVI)
nvimin = lowest(nvim, longitudNVI)
azul = (nvi - nvim) * 100/ (nvimax - nvimin)

xmf = mfi(srcMfi, longitudMFI)

mult=input(2.0, title="Multiplicador para derivacion estandar" , group="Bollinger Oscillator")
boLength=input(25, title="Calculation length ", group="Bollinger Oscillator" )

// Bands Calculation
basis = sma(tprice, boLength) //Find the 20-day moving average average (n1 + n2 ... + n20)/20
dev = mult * stdev(tprice, boLength) //Find the standard deviation of the 20-days
upper = basis + dev //Upper Band = 20-day Moving Average + (2 x standard deviation of the 20-days)
lower = basis - dev //Lower Band = 20-day Moving Average - (2 x standard deviation of the 20-days)
OB1 = (upper + lower) / 2.0
OB2 = upper - lower

BollOsc = ((tprice - OB1) / OB2 ) * 100 // percent b
xrsi = rsi(tprice, 14)

calc_stoch(src, length,smoothFastD ) =>
    ll = lowest(low, length)
    hh = highest(high, length)
    k = 100 * (src - ll) / (hh - ll)
    sma(k, smoothFastD)

stoc = calc_stoch(tprice, 21, 3)

marron = (xrsi + xmf + BollOsc + (stoc / 3))/2
verde = marron + oscp
media = ema(marron,m)
bandacero= 0

///// BACKTEST PERIOD ///////
testStartYear = input(2021, "Backtest Start Year")
testStartMonth = input(1, "Backtest Start Month")
testStartDay = input(1, "Backtest Start Day")
testPeriodStart = timestamp(testStartYear,testStartMonth,testStartDay,0,0)

testStopYear = input(9999, "Backtest Stop Year")
testStopMonth = input(12, "Backtest Stop Month")
testStopDay = input(31, "Backtest Stop Day")
testPeriodStop = timestamp(testStopYear,testStopMonth,testStopDay,0,0)

testPeriod() =>
    time >= testPeriodStart and time <= testPeriodStop ? true : false

//if testPeriod()
//   if strategy.position_size == 0 or strategy.position_size > 0
 //       strategy.entry(id="long", long=true, when = entry_long, comment="Enter Long Comment")
 //       strategy.close(id="long", when=exit_long, comment = "Exit Long Comment")

//    if strategy.position_size == 0 or strategy.position_size < 0
//        strategy.entry(id="short", long=false, when = entry_short, comment="Enter Short Comment")
//        strategy.close(id="short", when=exit_short, comment = "Exit Short Comment")





vl=plot(verde, color=#66FF66, style=plot.style_area, title="verde")// COLOURED(102,255,102) as “verde” , GREEN
ml=plot(marron, color= #FFCC99, style=plot.style_area, title="marron", transp=0) // COLOURED(255,204,153) as"marron" , BEIGE
al=plot(azul, color=#00FFFF, style=plot.style_area, title="azul") // COLOURED(0,255,255) as “azul” ,
plot(marron, color= #330000, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2, title="lmarron") // COLOURED(51,0,0) as “lmarron” ,
plot(verde, color=#006600, style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2, title="lineav") // COLOURED(0,102,0) as “lineav” ,
plot(azul, color=#000066, style=plot.style_line, title="lazul" ) // COLOURED(0,0,102) as “lazul” ,
plot(media, color=color.red, title="media", style=plot.style_line, linewidth=2) // COLOURED(255,0,0) as “media” ,
plot(bandacero, color=color.black, title="cero") // COLOURED(0,0,0) as "cero"
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?